# Using a cspline interpolation in Gekko Optimizer

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I am trying to use a cspine interpolation in my gekko model. In this problem there is a power plant, a steam turbine, and a grid. The turbine will have different efficiencies based on the amount of it's capacity being used to meet the grid. I have tried to implement a gekko cspline and then have the model call that to give the efficiency for each time point based on the power production. I haven't been able to get this to work. Is this possible in Gekko?

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Grid demand
t = np.linspace(0, 24, 24)
e_grid = 2.5*np.sin(t/24*(2*np.pi)) + 5

# Turbine Efficiency curve based on turbine capacity
pcap = np.linspace(.1, 1, 10)  # %capacity
cap = 10*pcap
turb_eff = .75*np.sin(cap/11*np.pi)

# build model
m = GEKKO(remote=True)
m.time = t

Econs = m.Param(e_grid)
Egen = m.MV(value=5, lb=0, ub=10)  # steam production

x = m.Param(value=cap)
y = m.Var()
Turb_spline = m.cspline(x, y, cap, turb_eff)

turb_out = m.Intermediate(Egen*Turb_spline)
m.Equation(Econs == turb_out)
m.Obj(Egen)

m.options.IMODE = 5
m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.solve()

plt.plot(t, Egen.value, label='gen')
plt.plot(t, Econs.value, label='cons')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('Energy')
plt.legend()
```

I was able to get this to work using `np.polyfit`. I then was able to add a Polynomial into my gekko model and run it to get the correct adjusting of the efficiencies. I used the following code instead of a cspline.

```
Ecap = m.Intermediate(Egen/cap)
m.Equation(turb_eff == p[0]*Ecap**5 + p[1]*Ecap**4 + p[2]*Ecap**3 + p[3]*Ecap**2 + p[4]*Ecap + p[5])
turb_out = m.Intermediate(Egen*turb_eff)
m.Equation(turb_out == Econs)
```

I would still like know how to use a cspline so that I can fit more complicated models that a polynomial is unable to capture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, I would write the Objective function like below.

[image]

Please see the code. This is still very crude so that you might need to modify it, but I hope you can get an idea.
The output of `m.cspline` function cannot be saved to the other variable. You can just call the x or y variable as you need.
The time arrays between variables don't match in your code.

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Grid demand
t = np.linspace(0, 50, 50)
e_grid = 2.5*np.sin(t/24*(2*np.pi)) + 5

# Turbine Efficiency curve based on turbine capacity
pcap = np.linspace(.1, 1, 10)  # %capacity
cap = 10*pcap
turb_eff = 0.75*np.sin(cap/11*np.pi)

# build model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = t

Econs = m.Param(e_grid)
Egen = m.MV(value=5, lb=0, ub=20)  # steam production
Egen.STATUS = 1

x = m.Var()
y = m.Var()
m.Equation(x==Egen)
m.cspline(x, y, cap, turb_eff, bound_x=True)

w1 = 10
w2 = 0
w3 = 0

turb_out = m.Var()
m.Equation(turb_out == Egen*y)
m.Obj(w1*(turb_out - Econs)**2 + w2*Egen**2)

m.options.IMODE = 6
m.solve()

print(np.max(Egen.value))

plt.figure(0)
plt.plot(cap,turb_eff, 'b.', label='data')
plt.plot(x.value[1:], y.value[1:], 'ro', label='Interpolate')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(t[1:], turb_out[1:], label='Turb_out')
plt.plot(t[1:], Egen[1:], label='Egen')
plt.plot(t[1:], Econs[1:],'r--', label='Econs')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('Energy')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(t[1:], y[1:], label='Turb_eff')
plt.legend()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Junho! I was able to get your code to run by also adding the equation: `m.Equation(Econs == turb_out)`

Comment: this is close to doing what I want it to. The thing that needs to happen is that the efficiency is only dependant on the amount of its capacity that is being used. It should have peak efficiency of .75 when the energy production is at 5.5. The efficiency should be at .2 when the energy production is at 1 or 10. Is there a way to get the values so that the efficiency changes based on the power output?

Comment: Andrew, could you try it with m.Equation(turb_out == Egen*`x`) instead of `y`?  And, also change the weights w1, w2, and w3 to get an anticipated result. I would try a bigger w1, like 1000, to equalize 'turb_out' and 'Econs'.

Comment: I edited the code and charts above. Let me know if that isn't what you expected. I also changed the Obj function.

Comment: That makes more sense with the weights. The main issue is getting the efficiency based on the Egen out put. If I were to do the energy balance with interp1d instead of the m.cspline I would put    ``` eff = interp1d(cap, turb_eff); turb_out = Egen*eff(Egen); Econs = turb_out``` The interpolation is supposed to change the power output into what the efficiency would be for that power output. The Egen should be higher than the turb_out because it is loosing power the the given inefficiency in the turbine at that output.

Comment: Changing the y to an x made it so that the turbine is creating energy instead of converting it. Does the above comment help clarify at all?

Comment: I edited the code once again. I changed `x` back to `y` and linked `x` to `Egen` using the additional equation `m.Equation(x==Egen)`.

Comment: Based on the example efficiency curve, 'Turb_out' goes down when steam generation (Egen) passes ~7.1. So, the solver can only return the steam generation at ~7.1 as a maximum value.